# Is there an incremental GC available for mono that I can use or get the source code for?

Tags: .net, mono, garbage-collection

I'm writing tools for building games in .NET using functional style. For this, I will need an incremental GC, or some type of GC whose collection times are bounded to 1 ms or so. I read a paper on a real-time incremental GC that is a WIP for mono, but I can't find anyway to look at its code or to use it - http://static.usenix.org/event/vm04/wips/goh.pdf

To clarify what I mean by 'incremental GC', an incremental GC splits an individual garbage collection cycle into multiple slices of work that can be interleaved with program execution so that each slice can be processed in a relatively bounded amount of time. The primary intent of an incremental GC feature is to support soft-real-time applications by keeping them consistently responsive at a relatively fine-grained level. Incremental GCs elide the 'embarrassing pause' caused by mainstream GCs such as .NET's generational GC. Many systems that use incremental GC have collection pauses bound roughly at 1ms. This is perfect for games as they need to run their whole cycle inside 16.667ms. The .NET generational GC, OTOH, will cause typical pauses of 200ms.

I really would like to avoid sinking the time into writing my own incremental GC for mono, so if someone could tell me what alternative (soft)real-time centric GCs are currently available, that would be great. If I need to write my own GC, it would be great to have an open source GC that would serve as a good reference for someone writing their own mono GC from scratch.

**EDIT: added elaboration of what is meant by 'incremental' GC.**

Comment: Cody, I'm afraid you are wrong about generational GC's being incremental. It is a common mistake to conflate incrementalism with generationalism. They are aboslutey orthogonal. I suggest some general research on incremental GCs (perhaps start with the Train Algorithm as that's how I familiarized myself with them http://cs.au.dk/~beta/Papers/Train/train.html). GHC also has an expiremental incremental GC descirbed here - http://pubs.doc.ic.ac.uk/incremental-garbage-barrier/incremental-garbage-barrier.pdf . A typical stop-the-world time for my apps is around 200 ms. Definitely unacceptable.

Comment: Here's a thread that gives some more background on the subject, the explaining the non-relation between incremental and generational algorithms - http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/103653.aspx and http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/Some/0/75351

Comment: I don't really have time to read through all of those articles, unfortunately. And I'm also not sure what happened to my comment. I assume that a couple of people flagged it as spam (??!) because you thought it was incorrect, which caused it to be automatically removed. I said that a generational garbage collector is always incremental because it does not collect all of the objects during a single collection cycle, but that the converse does not necessarily hold (e.g., an incremental garbage collector is not necessarily incremental). Perhaps it's a difference in definition of terminology.

Comment: Ack, that's my bad. I can't down-vote yet, so I marked it as 'unhelpful'. Didn't realize it would disappear or be consider spam. At any rate, your definition of incremental is of the more ad hoc sort and is unrelated to my definition I'm using, which is the more formal sort. The formal definition of incremental involves splitting a single collection cycle into multiple slices of work that can be done in a relatively bounded amount of time. The formal definition is used here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Stop-the-world_vs._incremental_vs._concurrent

Comment: @BryanEdds: you can't down-vote comments at all.  On-topic, .NET 4 includes a background GC which might impact you less (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#background_garbage_collection), though I doubt that's made it to Mono yet either.

Comment: Also, I'd say 200ms GCs seem pretty high.  On what basis do you quote that time for a typical GC?  Gen0/1 collections should be a lot lower than that (sub-10ms), and you shouldn't be having too many unexpected Gen2 collections in a typical game (because most resources are either cached indefinitely or too transient to get to Gen2).  Is this something you're hypothesising, or have you profiled this in live code?

Comment: @CodyGray "I said that a generational garbage collector is always incremental". That is incorrect. http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/i.html#incremental.garbage.collection

Comment: @Dan - thanks for your link and your support! also, I should have been more specific with the timings I quoted. Those are timings only for gen 2 collections. gen 0 / 1 collections are less menacing.

Comment: @Dan - these numbers are from stand-alone tests I've made, not from production code. So it's more speculation at this point.

Comment: Without knowing more detail (but having some .NET game dev experience), a rough approach would be to cache long-term resources, then force Gen2 GC when you know you've released everything, and the delay can be handled sensibly (e.g. level load time). Then, optimise to minimise the chance of anything surviving Gen0/1 GC.  If transient objects are released before a Gen1 GC, you can prevent Gen2 allocations & GCs happening unexpectedly.  In general: careful design, and lots of profiling. I guess I'd rather not be coding a custom GC when there are games to make! ;-)

Comment: @BryanEdds: I *would* be interested in seeing your tools though!

Comment: @Dan - what I have so far is linked here - https://github.com/bryanedds/aml . As for there being games to make, well, I've already accepted that what the industry is doing is so badly broken that building many things from the ground up is a necessary evil. OTOH, if some simple optimization techniques are all that is required, I would avoid writing a new GC. But time will tell as my tools progress :)

Comment: What do you mean by "what the industry is doing?"

Comment: Imperative programming and / or object-orientation by default. Needs to be changed to functional and / or declarative programming by default.

Comment: Not sure I agree, but it's an interesting direction!  I'll keep an eye on it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14853/discussion-between-dan-puzey-and-bryan-edds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is an incremental GC for Mono with sources - but there is one (targeted for an oCaml-derived language) that is both open source and seems to be focused on high-performance called [HLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669342/is-there-an-incremental-gc-available-for-mono-that-i-can-use-or-get-the-source-c). The author, Jon Harrop also has a blog [here](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.co.uk/) with many excellent articles on garbage collection and related technologies.

Hope this helps!